# What sequence has this Discrete Fourier Transform?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose
$$
x[n]=
\begin{cases}
x_i &, i \in P\\
0  &, i \notin P
\end{cases}
$$
where $P \subset \{0,1, \cdots,N-1 \}$ and $|P|=K$ and $x_i \geq 0$.

Suppose these equalities hold :
$$
|X[1]|=||X[2]|=\cdots=|X[N-1]|
$$
where 
$$ 
X[k] = \sum_{i \in P}x_ie^{-j\frac{2\pi}Nik} = DFT[x] 
$$
how may we recover the signal $x[n]$?

Note that $|X[0]|$ is not involved in the equalities.

I know there are $K$ unknowns and $N-2$ equations, and in general this doesn't have a solution but I'm looking for the cases where there is a solution?

Also when there is not a solution, how can we find the least square solution of this system of equations?

Comment: What is the relation between $K$ and $N$? And what is small $k$?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi $K < N - 2$. small $k$ is index of values of $X[k]$

Comment: So the DC component is unknown, but the magnitude of all other spectral components is constant? Other than that, all you know is that the signal is sparse in the time domain? What about the phase? Nonetheless, $x[n]$ is going to be impulse-like just because of reciprocity (assuming that $|X[i]|\neq 0$). I'd start there. You may also find some of the sparse signal reconstruction work useful. The short answer to your question though, is an impulse-like function.

Comment: Hint: the Fourier of the Shah function is the Shah function.

Comment: the Shah function is a continuous-time signal and I think we can't use its properties here.

Comment: Just in case you're interested: your question [made it into Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Stack+Exchange/@40.708793,-74.006756,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sNI4VOv1ukYkAAAQIt-PqAQ!2e0!3e2!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xf9742bc540e39399) ;-)